# Orchard: write straight SQL to retrieve content records with where on some fields?

Tags: orchardcms

I am building a website that has dynamic content.

Because of the customer requirement, the website CANNOT built be any CMS, but I still needs a data entry tool for data records. I am hoping to use Orchard purely as a data entry tool, not mentioning that Orchard comes with the admin interface security, publish/unpublish, etc., which are nice to have.

The content record has the following fields:

```
title
body
date 1
date 2
```

I created the content type in Orchard and entered a few records. Now I need to write straight SQL to get content records out based on conditions on date 1 and date 2 fields. After examining Orchards's all tables, I am unable to figure out how to get records out with a single SQL statement.

Any direct or indirect approach?

The reason that I am hoping to use Orchard (not Drupal, etc.) as the data entry tool is that I hope to persuade the customer to rebuild the website's with Orchard too in the future. At this moment, the website is built with ASP.NET and Razor.

Any input is really appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: When you say front-end, do you mean the web page and it's HTML, CSS and Javascript?

Comment: Robert, you are correct. Thanks for chiming in.

Comment: Well, I'm a bit baffled by the distinction.  Why should anyone care where this logic is implemented if it works?

Comment: What are you baffled about? I can reword the question if needed.

Comment: Well, for starters, who writes an entire CMS in the web page?  And why does it matter to the customer if Javascript is involved, or whether the initials CMS are attached to it?

Comment: I am a bit baffled too:-) I reworded the post. Basically, I need to have protected interface to store records. Besides, I need to make them publish or unpublished as needed. Orchard suits this purpose nicely. But I am not going to use Orchard to build the website. Orchard in my case is just a data entry tool. But it has its own table design. I need to get the data out with straight SQL.